# How to nest loops using outer index in inner start evaluation in CoffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

How to write two nested loops in CoffeeScript: where the inner loop is using the outer loop current index as its initial value?

ie

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = i; j < array.size; j++) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most succinct way I could think of:

```
for item, i in array    
    for item, j in array when j >= i
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, maybe:

```
for i in array
  for j in [i ... array.size()]
    console.log i, j
```

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. I'm using processing and weirdly "array.size()" seemed to be processed by processing.js and failed.